# Android JNI : Why ReleaseByteArrayElements does NOT copy back data

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In function:

```
jint Java_cn_vl_video_Encoder_encode(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jlong handle, jbyteArray in, jint in_size, jbyteArray out)
```

out is a byte array in Java.

There are some code like this:

```
char * h264Buf = (char*) (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, out, &h264Buf_isCopy);
jint out_size = vl_video_encoder_encode(handle_t, FRAME_TYPE_AUTO, buf, in_size, &h264Buf);
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, out, (jbyte*)h264Buf, 0);
```

I have printed some log in jni code, h264Buf have some correct data.
But after release byte array, out is total 0 in Java.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you sure that the contents of `h264buf` are being modified?  It seems a bit odd that `vl_video_encoder_encode()` is taking the address of a pointer rather than the address of a buffer.  If it's doing its work in a separate buffer, and then returning an updated pointer, you won't see any changes in the buffer allocated from Java code.  (If that's the case, you'll need to `memcpy()` the data into the byte array yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

When you say '`out` is total 0' you seem to be expecting the number of elements in the array to magically change. That isn't, and can't possibly be, how it works. Note that you aren't passing `out_size` to `ReleaseByteArrayElements()`, not that you can, so how can it know the array has changed size?

Comment: ReleaseByteArrayElements() does not need to know the size of array.